# create an instance of com.lowagie.text.Image from byte[]

Tags: java, jsp, itext

I am working on a web-app that allows user to send some pictures to server and then server sends back a pdf file which contains those pictures and some additional data. I was able to receive pictures on my server side. Basically I have them as byte[]. To create pdf file I use iText. In order to embed pictures I have to use com.lowagie.text.Image object. However, how to create instance of com.lowagie.text.Image from byte[] that I have?

Comment: You'll need to state how the images were encoded into bytes before anyone can tell you how to interpret the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In com.lowagie.text.Image there is a method getInstance() that is overloaded to take different inputs, including String filename and byte[] imgb. (See http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/com/lowagie/text/Image.html#getInstance%28URL%29 )

```
com.lowagie.text.Image image01 = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance("test.jpg");
document.add(image01);

byte[] byte_array = .......

com.lowagie.text.Image image02 = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(byte_array);
document.add(image02);
```